# False discovery control across time?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

Suppose I have a set of $N$ securities (stocks, bonds, whatever), and for each security a decomposition into a linear regression on $k$ common factors: $s_i = \alpha_i + \sum_{j=1}^k \beta_{ik}f_k$. Here $\beta_{ik}$ is the coefficient for factor $k$ for security $i$, and $s_i$ is the 1-day return. Suppose that the data for each security is a window of $w$ days, used to fit the regression.

My understanding is that we can then perform hypothesis tests to get $P(\alpha_i > 0)$ for each of the $\alpha_i$. However, as we have $N$ such tests (assume independent for now), we need to control the number of false rejections of the null $\alpha_i \leq 0$.

The question: suppose I perform this set of regressions every $t$ days, generating a new set of $N$ hypothesis tests. What's the appropriate way to test $P(\alpha_i > 0)$ for this new set of tests, controlling for the false discovery rate? Is possible that discarding the results of the previous tests biases FDR methods that are supposed to work on one complete sample of tests?

Comment: How do you intend to 'control' the number of false rejections in the first part?

Comment: Given the p-values for each of the alphas, it seems like it should be possible to apply the Benjamini-Hochberg correction or Bonferroni to control the FDR.

The question is, if I then conduct another set of tests in the future which won't be used in conjunction with the previous set of tests, are there any biases introduced by assuming that the previous tests were never conducted?